# Click outside the modal dialogue to make it disapprar

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, automated-tests

I'm writing a javascript test to test that when a Modal dialogue is open on the web page, and when a click event happens outside the modal dialogue, the dialogue would be closed.

Apparently, when the dialogue is open, rest of the page remains frozen. I'm not able to find a way to click outside the dialogue.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Could please provide some code ? Will be helpfull

Comment: If you have an overlay to your modal-window, then add a click event listener on the overlay and code to close or hide the modal-window. An example of what you've done so far would be helpful for a specific solution

Comment: I have to click outside of the modal using automated script. how do I do that?